# ProductList filter on react.js

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, eclipse, filter

I would like to create a function that allows you to filter products by category. I already tried to make this creating a query on Java but it dosen't work, so i thought it can be easier to do on the frontend.

This is my code at the moment:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { ContextProductList } from '../app';
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown';


function Filter() {
    
    const categoryList = [
        { label: 'Tutto', value: "All" },
        { label: 'Roll', value: 'Roll' },
        { label: 'Sashimi', value: 'Sashimi' },
        { label: 'Uramaki', value: 'Uramaki' },
        { label: 'Bevande', value: 'Bevande' },
        { label: 'Dessert', value: 'Dessert' },
        { label: 'Ramen', value: 'Ramen' },
        { label: 'Speciali', value: 'Special' },
        { label: 'Altro', value: 'Altro' }
    ];
    const [category , setCategory] = useState('');
    const [productList, setProductList] = useContext(ContextProductList);


   const handleCategoryChange = (event) => {
    const selectedCategory = event.target.value;
    setCategory(selectedCategory);

    // Filtra la lista di prodotti in base alla categoria selezionata
    const filteredProductList = productList.filter(product => {
      if (selectedCategory === "All") {
        // Se l'utente ha selezionato "Tutto", mostra tutti i prodotti
        return true;
      } else {
        // Altrimenti, filtra i prodotti per la categoria selezionata
        return product.category === selectedCategory;
      }
    });

    // Aggiorna lo stato di productList con i prodotti filtrati
    setProductList(filteredProductList);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="categorySelect">Seleziona una categoria:</label>
      <Dropdown value={category} options={categoryList} placeholder="Seleziona una categoria" onChange={handleCategoryChange} />
    </form>
  );
}

export default Filter;
```

I also give you the backend code in case the filtering can be done from there, i specify the filtering has to be done by prodocuts inserted by userShop because in my programm there may be more userShop who can insert product:

Repository

```
List<Product> findByCategoryAndUserShop(String id, String category);
    List<Product> findByUserShopId(String id);

//String id refers to userShop, not the product
```

Service:

```
List<Product> getAllProductsByCategoryForUserShop(String id, String category);
List<Product> getProductsByUserShop(String id);
```

ServiceImplements

```
@Override
      public List<Product> getAllProductsByCategoryForUserShop(String id, String category) {
        
        List<Product> products = null;
        if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            products = productRepository.findByUserShopId(id);
            System.out.println(products.toString());
        } else if (!category.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            products = productRepository.findByCategoryAndUserShop(id, category);
            System.out.println(category);
            System.out.println(products.toString());
        }
        return products;

    }
```

Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/products/{id}/{category}")
     public List<Product> getProductsByCategory(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String category) {
         System.out.println(id + category);
         
         return productService.getAllProductsByCategoryForUserShop(id, category);
     }
```

On the frontend it only works once, if i select another category the list empties, i think the problem is to be that, once the product list is filtered with the first filter, this filtered list is stored in the state of productList, and then when another filter is applied, the original product list is lost and replaced with the filtered list. So if a category is selected that doesn't exist in the filtered list, no products will be shown.
Instead, on the backend, i tried this method on Postman, if i use "all" it gets all the products that usershop inserted, but if i select a category it returns NULL.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new state that will store only Filtered data eg : filterData. and if there is no data in filterData you can return your productList.

```
<form>
  <label htmlFor="categorySelect">Seleziona una categoria:</label>
  <Dropdown value={category} options={filterData && filterData.length?filterData:categoryList} placeholder="Seleziona una categoria" onChange={handleCategoryChange} />
</form>
```

you can try in this way,